# How to create html-like navigation dropdown menu in React Native?

Tags: react-native, drop-down-menu

Is there a way to create a dropdown navigation menu like in HTML with React Native where the dropdown part is positioned absolute on top of the content that's below the menu?

Without absolute positioning, the dropdown's parent element (image below, blue background) increases its height and the other content is below the dropdown.

When I use position absolute on the dropdown, it's above Item 1 and not below it because React Natives position absolute positions relative to the parent.

My Code:

```
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>

      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'baseline', backgroundColor: '#3763a4'}}>

        <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#FF0000', flex: 1 }}>

          <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>

            <Text style={{ color: '#FFFFFF' }}>Item 1</Text>

          </View>

          <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>

            <Text style={{ color: '#FFFFFF' }}>Item 1.1</Text>

            <Text style={{ color: '#FFFFFF' }}>Item 1.2</Text>

          </View>

        </View>

        <View style={{ padding: 10, backgroundColor: '#FF0000', flex: 1 }}><Text style={{ color: '#FFFFFF' }}>Item 2</Text></View>

        <View style={{ padding: 10, backgroundColor: '#FF0000', flex: 1 }}><Text style={{ color: '#FFFFFF' }}>Item 3</Text></View>

      </View>

      <WebView

        source={myHtml}

      />

    </View>
```

How it looks like:

[image: my menu]

The Webview is below this. Instead, the dropdown should be positioned in top of the Webview.

How it looks like with position absolute:
[image]

I hope my explanation is clear enough. This image and link shows a HTML navigation menu: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown_navbar.asp
[image]

Comment: you can checkout github code https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/components/overflow-menu/overview#overflowmenu or select is what u want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. I had to wrap the absolute positioned View in another View and add zIndex: 1 to position it on top of the Webview.

Code:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>

                <View style={{ zIndex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'baseline', backgroundColor: '#3763a4' }}>

                    <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#FF0000', flex: 1 }}>

                        <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>

                            <Text style={{ color: '#FFFFFF' }}>Item 1</Text>

                        </View>

                        <View>

                            <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#FF0000', padding: 10, position: 'absolute' }}>

                                <Text style={{ color: '#FFFFFF' }}>Item 1.1</Text>

                                <Text style={{ color: '#FFFFFF' }}>Item 1.2</Text>

                            </View>

                        </View>

                    </View>

                    <View style={{ padding: 10, backgroundColor: '#FF0000', flex: 1 }}><Text style={{ color: '#FFFFFF' }}>Item 2</Text></View>

                    <View style={{ padding: 10, backgroundColor: '#FF0000', flex: 1 }}><Text style={{ color: '#FFFFFF' }}>Item 3</Text></View>

                </View>

                <WebView

                    source={myHTML}

                />

</View>
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Absolute position exists in RN: https://reactnative.dev/docs/layout-props#position, it works almost same as on CSS. Try and investigate!

Comment: I already tried it. In CSS it's relative to the element's position but in React Native it's relative to the parent. That's a huge difference. The React Native docs say that `If you want to position a child relative to something that is not its parent, don't use styles for that. Use the component tree.`. I don't know how I can use the component tree to achieve what I want though.

Comment: On Windows but does this make a difference?

Comment: I mean android simulator ? React native have some effects with children views on android, when you add absolute position to you `Item 1.1 Item1.2` menu, parent view cut off it ?

Comment: I write the app for Windows and iOS, not Android.

Comment: OK, I got it, I didn't have time now, if nobody answer you today, I'll send you tomorrow how dropdown menu may implemented on RN. Good luck!